# OpenVINO 1D CNN inference device didn't appear after reboot with MYRIAD but could work with CPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, openvino

My environment is Windows 11 with openvino_2022.1.0.643 version.

I use `mo --saved_model_dir=. -b=1 --data_type=FP16` to generate IR files.

The input of the model is a binary file contained 240 bytes data.

And it works fine with CPU when I run `benchmark_app`.

[image]

But `benchmark_app` cannot execute with NCS2 correctly.

```
[Step 10/11] Measuring performance (Start inference asynchronously, 4 inference requests, inference only: True, limits: 60000 ms duration)
[ INFO ] Benchmarking in inference only mode (inputs filling are not included in measurement loop).
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEvent:361   Condition failed: event->header.flags.bitField.ack != 1[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEventWithPerf:373    addEvent(event, timeoutMs) method call failed with an error: 3[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] XLinkReadData:156      Condition failed: (addEventWithPerf(&event, &opTime, 0xFFFFFFFF))[0m
[31mF: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] dispatcherEventReceive:92        Duplicate id detected.
[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] getGraphMonitorResponseValue:1901       XLink error, rc: X_LINK_ERROR[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] handleIncomingEvent:676  handleIncomingEvent() Read failed -2
[0m
[31mF: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherResponseServe:852       no request for this response: XLINK_WRITE_RESP 1
[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncGraphQueueInference:3453      Can't get trigger response[0m
[31mF: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherResponseServe:852       no request for this response: XLINK_WRITE_RESP 1
[0m
[ ERROR ] Failed to queue inference: NC_ERROR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\john0\openvino_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\benchmark\main.py", line 451, in run
    duration_ms = f"{benchmark.first_infer(requests):.2f}"
  File "c:\users\john0\openvino_env\lib\site-packages\openvino\tools\benchmark\benchmark.py", line 79, in first_infer
    requests.wait_all()
RuntimeError: Failed to queue inference: NC_ERROR[35mE: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] handleIncomingEvent:676        handleIncomingEvent() Read failed -2
[0m
[31mF: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherResponseServe:852
[35mE: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] handleIncomingEvent:676  handleIncomingEvent() Read failed -2
[0m
no request for this response: XLINK_WRITE_RESP 1
[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=433
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [EventRead00Thr] handleIncomingEvent:676  handleIncomingEvent() Read failed -2
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[31mF: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherResponseServe:852       no request for this response: XLINK_WRITE_RESP 1
[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEvent:361   Condition failed: event->header.flags.bitField.ack != 1[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEventWithPerf:373    addEvent(event, timeoutMs) method call failed with an error: 3[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] XLinkReadData:156      Condition failed: (addEventWithPerf(&event, &opTime, 0xFFFFFFFF))[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] getGraphMonitorResponseValue:1901       XLink error, rc: X_LINK_ERROR[0m
[33mW: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncFifoDestroy:3161      myriad NACK
[0m
[Warning][VPU][MyriadPlugin] ncFifoDelete result NC_ERROR
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEvent:361   Condition failed: event->header.flags.bitField.ack != 1[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEventWithPerf:373    addEvent(event, timeoutMs) method call failed with an error: 3[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] XLinkReadData:156      Condition failed: (addEventWithPerf(&event, &opTime, 0xFFFFFFFF))[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] getGraphMonitorResponseValue:1901       XLink error, rc: X_LINK_ERROR[0m
[33mW: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncFifoDestroy:3161      myriad NACK
[0m
[[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
Warning][VPU][MyriadPlugin[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54 Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CLOSE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
] ncFifoDelete result NC_ERROR
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_WRITE_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEvent:361   Condition failed: event->header.flags.bitField.ack != 1[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] addEventWithPerf:373    addEvent(event, timeoutMs) method call failed with an error: 3[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [] XLinkReadData:156      Condition failed: (addEventWithPerf(&event, &opTime, 0xFFFFFFFF))[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] getGraphMonitorResponseValue:1901       XLink error, rc: X_LINK_ERROR[0m
[33mW: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncGraphDestroy:2232     myriad NACK
[0m
[Warning][VPU][MyriadPlugin] Deallocate Graph result NC_ERROR.
[36mI: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncDeviceClose:1708      Removing device...[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_CLOSE_STREAM_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [xLinkWinUsb] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] usb_bulk_write:467
WinUsb_WritePipe failed with error:=22
[0m
[35mE: [global] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] dispatcherEventSend:54   Write failed (header) (err -2) | event XLINK_RESET_REQ
[0m
[35mE: [xLink] [         0] [Scheduler00Thr] sendEvents:1150   Event sending failed[0m
[35mE: [ncAPI] [         0] [] ncDeviceClose:1851      Device didn't appear after reboot[0m
[36mI: [ncAPI] [         0] [] destroyDeviceHandle:1651        Destroying device handler[0m
```

Is it a bug with 1D CNN using NCS2 in API 2.0?

But 1D CNN seems unsupported in the past version.

Update with my files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qk77p81Vao4Loh5Reqyi3XmTbSbok17a/view?usp=sharing).

(The ZIP file contains 3 IR files and 1 input file.)

The following is the benchmark command I used.

`benchmark_app -m saved_model.xml -i A4C_LV_V.bin -d MYRIAD`

I have tried Windows 10 with openvino_2022.1.0.643 version.

But face with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up till now, Windows 11 is still officially **not** supported. The OpenVINO system requires Microsoft Windows 10, 64-bit. Issues are expected when OpenVINO is being used with an unsupported OS.

You'll need to consider to revert into Windows 10 environment instead.
You may refer to this [OpenVINO System Requirement](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html#doxid-openvino-docs-install-guides-installing-openvino-windows).

Comment: I have tried Windows 10 but in vain, and I update with my benchmark files, appreciate.

Comment: @TseHsien, I had checked your model with both latest (2022.1) and older (2021.4.2) OpenVINO versions. As you mentioned, this model is not supported in the older version of OV (I've got the Unknown model format error). As for the latest version, I faced the same issue as yours (able to infer on CPU but failed on NCS2-device didn't appear after reboot and failed to read output from FIFO: NC_Error. We'll further investigate this and will get back to you asap.

Comment: @TseHsien, Please note that current support for the 1D CNN model for OpenVINO 2022.1 is only enabled for CPU.

As for MYRIAD, our development team will assess the request and you may refer to our Release Notes for potential future enablement.